# Mongo database: search for text escaping some characters

Tags: regex, mongodb, search, find, escaping

I'm looking for a way to search text on my MongoDB escaping some characters.

For example:

In the collection `contacts` there is a document with "john.doe" in field `name`

```
{
  _id: ID
  ...
  name : "john.doe",
  ...
}
```

("john.doe" could be "j.ohndoe" or "j.o.h.n.d.o.e" or "jo.hn.do.e", you name it)

I want to find it searching for "johndoe", **not only "john.doe" (ignoring ".")**. It would be great to use directly `findOne`.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible using purely MongoDB queries. However, you can you MongoDB map reduce to get filtered documents or perform such actions on client side. I know it will not be an elegant solution but at least will work.

Please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

**Example**

```
function findByKey(key)
{
    var keys =
    db.contacts.mapReduce(function(){
        var re = /\./igm;
        var txt = this.name.replace(re,"");
        var re = new RegExp(u_name);

        if(re.exec(txt)!= null)
        {
            emit(1, this._id);
        }
    }, function(k, v){
        return {keys: v};
    }, 
    {
        out:{inline:true}, 
        scope: {u_name:key}
    });

    if(keys.results.length > 0)
    {
        var arKeys = keys.results[0].value.keys;
        return db.contacts.find({_id:{$in: arKeys}});
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
};

var data = findByKey("john doe");
```

After running above script, variable data will hold all documents having "john doe" including `j.ohn.doe` or `john.doe` so ignoring all periods.